# ContentControl & View Switching -- W8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, caliburn.micro

```
    <ContentControl cal:View.Context="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=TwoWay}" cal:View.Model="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

or

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CurrentView" />
```

both variants fail to run properyly, I am basically configured like the example for WinRT81 in samples folder but I don't have all example stuff.

What is really frustrating is that I have another application running with the exact same configuration.  View Switching is what I want to do with this application as well but for some reason (I don't see it) that it is unable to find the instance that is being assigned to CurrentView. I have done view switching before in WPF without issue in this fashion.
Which makes no senses since its a UserControl.  Any ideas why its cause this to occur, definitely an issue in config that don't see..

Caliburn.Micro current download was yesterday using V2 assemblies

Comment: every time it hits the Login usercontrol for some reason it attempts to locate it in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appears it was a desktop issue, laptop works just fine, will have to research this later.